# Retrieving a variable from another view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

The variable latitude in ViewController1 is visible. Why is the variable from another ViewController empty? Whenever I run the code the `.text` property of `ActualCoordinatesText` label is empty...

```
class ViewControllerGpsMaps: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var ActualCoordinatesText: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func GetCoordinates(_ sender: Any) {
        GetActualCoordinates()
    }

    public func GetActualCoordinates() {

        let sb = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController

        ActualCoordinatesText.text = sb.latitude

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where did you read about accessing the data this way? This is incorrect. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating a new instance of `ViewController1` that means that the data included is the initialized value...

If your `ViewControllerGPSMaps` is called by `VieController1` you should use the `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` of the `ViewController1` to "give" the data you want to transfer...

Comment: In viewcontroller1 I have a timer that changes variable ... prepare and segue every now and then it is used to prepare data and send .... I need to constantly receive new data from viewcontroller1 The only solution will be a notification center?

Comment: No, better solutions will be to either use a delegate function to pass the data pack to the parent viewController, or to inject a closure into a variable on viewController1 and execute that every time there is data to pass back.

Comment: Can you give some example of the last solution? Thanks.